# Signifiance of the Strictly Diagonallly Dominant matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Hello I am in a Numerical Analysis class and can't seem to find any information on this online or in the textbook.

```
Strictly Diagonallly Dominant = SDD
```

> What is the significance of the SDD matrix?
>   How does it relate to say the Jacobi Method or Gauss Seidel Method?
>    Is there any significant or interesting results relating to the eigenvalues of a SDD matrix?
>   Importance of SDD in a system $Ax=b$, if any?

If theirs anything else important I should know about SDD matrices please tell me!

Comment: Please, tell what SDD means.

Comment: @JeanMarie Strictly Diagonally Dominant

Comment: Thanks. All I know is that SDD matrices are invertible ( $\iff$ no $0$ eigenvalue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the significance of the SDD matrix?

There is a theorem called Gerschgorin's circle theorem that depends on SDD matrices.

> How does it relate to say the Jacobi Method or Gauss Seidel Method? Is
>   there any significant

The Jacobi method and Gauss Seidel method converge if the matrix is SDD

> interesting results relating to the eigenvalues of a SDD matrix?

See Gershgorin's circle theorem. Every eigenvalue of $A$ lies within at least one of the discs.

> Importance of SDD in a system Ax=b, if any?

Both of the methods you mentioned solve the $Ax=b$ problem.